# Entity Framework 4 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have created MVC3 application using Entity Framework Code First method. My model is very simple:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int YearsAtCompany { get; set; }
}
```

and context class is

```
public class EmployeeDB : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

and controller looks like this:

```
EmployeeDB context = new EmployeeDB();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(context.Employees);
        }      
    }
```

I have created EmployeesDb.mdf and Employee table.

but I get this error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[DFEmployees.Models.Employee]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'DFEmployees.Models.Employee'.
```

[Updated]

```
@model DFEmployees.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

Please suggest solution.

Comment: Can you post the code of the View you are navigation to?

Comment: Not sure, but could it be that the View is typed as Employee instead of IEnumerable<Employee> ?

Comment: @Jason: I have added the view code. Please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like your view are waiting for a single employee, and you are triying to fill the view with a DBSet of employees.

To solve it, you can set the @model of the view to an IEnumerable of employees, or send only one employee to the view, depending of what are you showing in the view.

**EDIT**: I think this problem is not related with the previous one. Check this link, I hope it helps you: [LINK](http://www.marcusoft.net/2011/02/error-provider-did-not-return.html)

Comment: @Darin and @Jonathan: I used FirstOrDefault() and now I get this exception: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. and when I further hit F5 I get : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Your controller action returns a list of employees so adapt your model respectively in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<DFEmployees.Models.Employee>
```

Or if you wanted to use a single employee make sure you pass a single employee to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(context.Employees.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

and then you can have:

```
@model DFEmployees.Models.Employee
```